# How can I reduce slowdowns from mousemove event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mousemove

I'm running a relatively simple function (update a `span`'s `innerHTML`) on `mousemove`. The application is a [Leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/) map. When the mouse is moving, there is palpable lag when zooming, panning and loading tiles. I only need to update the `span` about 10-20 times per second at most. (See [here](http://map.agent-orange.ca/) for the page in question; the update is for the X/Z indicator in the upper-right corner.)

What's the best way to delay and/or defer `mousemove` event calls? Is it good enough to skip updating `innerHTML`? Can I unregister and re-register the event after a timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the mousemove set the `innerHTML` string to a variable and also use a direct plain DOM mousemove event on the element if feasible. See http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4398

```
!function () {
    var buffer = null;

    elem.onmousemove = function () {
        buffer = value;
    };

    !function k() {
        if (buffer) {
            span.innerHTML = buffer;
            buffer = null;
        }
        setTimeout(k, 100);
    }();

}();
```

Now the mousemove event hardly does any work (setting innerHTML is A LOT of work btw) and the span is updated 10 times per second.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Leaflet's `L.Map.on()` to bind the event, and it doesn't use jQuery, so I think it's using the DOM event already. Will synchronization be an issue with this method, or does Javascript take care of that well enough? What does the `!` before `function k()` do?

Comment: @HenryMerriam doing `function k(){}()` is a syntax error because it is parsed as function declaration, while `!function k(){}()` is parsed as an expression so it works. I am pretty sure `map.on` uses jQuery behind the curtains.

Comment: Nvm I digged through the source and they use their own event implementation, so that's fine I guess.

Answer (score 5):

Modifying the text node of the span will be much more efficient than modifying innerHTML.

```
function mouseMoveAction(ev) {
    span.firstChild.data = new Date.toString();
}
```

But if text nodes won't fulfill the requirement, and you need innerHTML on mousemove, you can use a threshold in the mousemove handler.

```
/* Keep CPUs to a minimum. */
var MOUSE_MOVE_THRESHOLD = 25,
    lastMouseMoveTime = -1;

function mousemoveCallback(ev) {
        var now = +new Date;
        if(now - lastMouseMoveTime < MOUSE_MOVE_THRESHOLD)
            return;
        lastMouseMoveTime = now;
        mouseMoveAction(ev);
}
```

Avoid jQuery, et al; they needlessly make things a lot slower and add a lot more complexity.